# why does image style opacity is not changing my image object in canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game that loads canvas first, then load all the images, but I am having problem with the opacity of each image, when I try to use "img.style.opacity = 0.5;" nothing changes in the image...
This is  a part of code:

```
     imageObj.src = "table.jpg";
    var tequila = new Image();
        tequila.src = "tequila.png";
        tequila.style.opacity = 0.5;
       wisky.onload = function(){
          context.drawImage(tequila, 180, 319);

        };


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawImage` draws the image you specify and does not look for any styling applied to the image.

However, the canvas' context has a property called `globalAlpha` (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-globalalpha), so you could set it to `0.5` before you draw the image, and reset it afterwards.

Comment: So If I want to change an specific img on my canvas, I can not do it, just change all the canvas opacity?

Comment: I have a question, if I want to reset the image, I hate to draw it again?

Comment: Solved, thank you mate,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_opacity) and place your images into the associated div containers.

**EDIT**: really, two downvotes for giving you the exact answer? :S

**FYI:** Opacity in Canvas is controlled with `globalAlpha` value as far as i know.

**EDIT 2:** This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949122/javascript-canvas-change-the-opacity-of-image)

> You have to either change `globalAlpha` or draw the image to an
>   off-screen canvas that has `globalAlpha` set, then draw this canvas
>   onto the main canvas.
>
> Just set alpha, draw the image and reset alpha back to full opacity.
>   Setting alpha does not change the content that is already drawn to the
>   canvas - it only applies to the next thing drawn (which would be the
>   image in this case).
>
> And of course, you can always prep your image with an alpha-channel in
>   case of PNG images.

Cheers to the downers :)

Comment: The question is asking about images on a canvas, not image elements in the DOM.

Comment: Opacity does not mean that one picture will be on top of another. Opacity is the opposite of translucency, and transparency is just complete translucency.

Comment: @Quentin Then he's using the wrong code because in a canva's in the `globalAlpha` value that controls opacity.

Comment: @codeCompiler77 You are correct. That is part of my answer.

Comment: @Toothbrush I'm salty for getting downvoted because he used a DOM function but mentioned canva's. I'm never going to get 15 rep at this rate haha. Well at least he has his answer now :)

Comment: Your answer would still have been wrong if the question was about images in the DOM. There's no requirement that `opacity` only be applied to div elements (or even elements that are `display: block`).

Comment: @codeCompiler77 I downvoted your answer because it seemed you didn't read the question or the code he posted. I have now removed my downvote and changed it to an upvote. Just be careful when you post an answer; make sure you read and _understand_ the question and code posted - I have also made the same mistake before.

Comment: @Quentin i never said that it was only for div elements, my preference is to contain everything inside of div's, which if it was in the DOM would have done what he wanted i believe?

Comment: @Toothbrush **Thanks** man, i went by the code (syntax) i saw and not the actual question. Cheers mate