# How do I change opacity of a new image object

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I'm trying to reduce the opacity of the image drawn on the canvas, but it isn't working

```
var img = new Image();
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

img.src = './picture.jpg';
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

img.style.opacity = 0.5;

ctx.drawImage(img, 30, 30, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: you have to set the alpha to the canvas element before drawing, not to the image (the image style is what the browser displays but not what the canvas element sees) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708618/draw-image-with-opacity-on-to-a-canvas#31708778

Comment: You the best man! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/// only image will have alpha affected:
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
context.drawImage(image, x, y);
context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949160/9161582